# Working With ViewModels In Kendo UI ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have Three  CaseCade Comboboxes, which work just fine for me
The problem is begins when I want to SAVE the id that Are Selected ,
I know how to get the Selected Id Which will be like this, and i have no problem with that

```
var countries = $("#countries").data("kendoDropDownList")
countries.value()
```

i don't know how to Set this values in my view model that i defined Above in My view, i don't know a way to pass view model to POST function.

This Is My View

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model Mfr.Admin.Models.Address.CreateViewModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Main.cshtml";
}
<
<div class="demo-section k-content">
<h4>Countries:</h4>
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=>m.CountryId)
      .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:100%"})
      .OptionLabel("Select Country...")
      .DataTextField("Title")
      .DataValueField("Id")
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetCascadeCountries", "Address");
          });
      })
      )

<h4 style="margin-top: 2em;">states:</h4>
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=>m.StateId)
      .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:100%"})
      .OptionLabel("Select state...")
      .DataTextField("stateTitle")
      .DataValueField("stateId")
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetCascadeStates", "Address")
                  .Data("filterStates");
          })
              .ServerFiltering(true);
      })
      .Enable(false)
      .AutoBind(false)
      .CascadeFrom("CountryId")
      )
<script>
    function filterStates() {
        return {
            countries: $("#CountryId").val()
        };
    }
</script>

<h4 style="margin-top: 2em;">cities:</h4>
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=>m.CityId)
        .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:100%"})
      .OptionLabel("Select city...")
      .DataTextField("cityTitle")
      .DataValueField("cityId")
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetCascadeCities", "Address")
                  .Data("filterCities");
          })
              .ServerFiltering(true);

      })
      .Enable(false)
      .AutoBind(false)
      .CascadeFrom("StateId")

      )
<script>
    function filterCities() {
        return {
            cities: $("#StateId").val()
        };
    }
</script>
<button class="k-button k-primary" id="get" style="margin-top: 2em; float:       right;">Save</button>

</div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#get").click(function () {
        // I want To call My post function Here,  and pass viewmodel with initialized values to that
        // I Suppose It will be something like this
        //but I dont know how to set values to view model
        //$.ajax({
        // url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Create", "Address"))",
       // type: "POST",
        // dataType: "json"
        //)};
    });
});

</script>
     <style>
   .k-readonly {
    color: gray;
}
```

This is My save Action

address here is not initialized

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel address)
    {
        if (address == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(address));

        var addressModel = new Address()
        {
            Description = address.Description,
            CityId = address.CityId,
            StateId = address.StateId,
            CountryId = address.CountryId,
            UserApplicationId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>()
        };

        _addressRepository.Add(addressModel);
        _addressRepository.Complete();

        return Json("");

    }
```

this is view model

```
public class CreateViewModel
   {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserApplicationId { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public int StateId { get; set; }

    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to send json back to controller

```
var countries = $("#countries").data("kendoDropDownList")
var countryId = countries.value();
var id = ..... //and so on

var data = {'Id': id, 'CountryId': countryId, /*ad so on*/ }

...
data: JSON.stringify(data)
...
```

Collect all data you need, put it in json object, stringify and if json properties correspond correctly to model properties, it will be automatically binded to controllers parameter.